# How to set a property in ant if another property start with a specific charcter?

Tags: ant

I am new to ant I am currently rewriting  a stuff which was written in groovy. I have a scenario where i want to set a property if some other property start with a  charter c

```
  if(version.startsWith('c')) {
            test_version = version.substring(1)
        }
else
{
test_version =version
}
```

I tried with conditional property but it seems I lost the way
Any pointer on this will be helpful

Comment: If you're using Java, then Ant has some Java libraries which let you configure/control an Ant built script from actual Java code.  There, you should be able to do this as you were doing with Groovy.

Comment: Though I am using java But Here I donot have the control to write a java code or custom task to do this stuff